# How to add integers together in two matrices using the zip() function in Python

Tags: python, zip

I cannot figure out how to add integers together in two matrices using the `zip()` function. Here is what I have:

```
matrix_a = [[3,6],[4,5]]

matrix_b = [[5,8],[6,7]]
```

I need to print out (using `zip()`):

```
[[8,14],[10,12]]
```

Comment: I have added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The following list comprehension will do the trick:

```
>>> [[x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(matrix_a, matrix_b)]
[[8, 14], [10, 2]]
```

If you want the version that uses loops:

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    current_list = []
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        current_list.append(x + y)
    result.append(current_list)
>>> result
[[8, 14], [10, 2]]
```

However, I definitely like more the comprehension version it is easier to read.

Comment: I believe that there is one extra layer of `[]` in the comprehension version.

Comment: @RiversShall, I just fixed my answer and added a version using for loops. Good catch!